# Validacion de 2 campos vacios

Tags: python-3.x, flutter

Sigo practicando con flet, ya funciona la operaciones matemáticas pero cuando valido si  los campos(Text) están vacíos(sin valores) y presionan el botón de sumar me debería salir mensaje de "ingresar valor" pero no me sale este mensaje de error " line 8, in sumar
txtresultado.value = int(int(valor1.value) +  int(valor2.value))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''  "

aquí les dejo el código
'''

import flet as ft

def main(page):

```
page.title = "Operaciones Matematicas"

def sumar(e):
    txtresultado.value = str(int(valor1.value) +  int(valor2.value))

    if valor1.value and valor2.value == "":
        valor1.error_text = "por favor ingrese primer valor"
        valor2.error_text = "por favor ingrese segundo valor"
    else:    
        page.update()

def restar(e):
    txtresultado.value = str(int(valor1.value) -  int(valor2.value))
    page.update()  

def multiplicar(e):
    txtresultado.value = str(int(valor1.value) *  int(valor2.value))
    page.update()

def dividir(e):
    txtresultado.value = str(int(valor1.value) /  int(valor2.value))
    page.update()            

page.add(ft.Text("Operaciones Matematicas", size=50, color="yellow"))

page.add(ft.Text(value="Ingrese 1er valor", color="yellow", size=20))
page.update()
valor1 = ft.TextField(hint_text="", width=200)
page.add(valor1)

page.add(ft.Text(value="Ingrese 2do valor", color="yellow", size=20))
page.update()
valor2 =ft.TextField(hint_text="", width=200)
page.add(valor2)

page.add(ft.ElevatedButton(
    text="+", 
    on_click = sumar,
    )
)
page.update()

page.add(ft.ElevatedButton(
    text="-", 
    on_click = restar, 
    )
)
page.update()

page.add(ft.ElevatedButton(
    text="*", 
    on_click = multiplicar, 
    )
)
page.update()

page.add(ft.ElevatedButton(
    text="/", 
    on_click = dividir, 
    )
)
page.update()


txtresultado = ft.TextField(hint_text="", width=200)
page.add(txtresultado)
page.update()
```

ft.app(target=main, view=ft.AppView.WEB_BROWSER)

'''

Comment: Antes de convertir a entero una cadena, debes asegurarte de que sea un número valido. Lo que yo uso habitualmente es intentar convertir a entero la cadena y capturar el ValueError resultante cuando no es posible la conversión.

Comment: De nuevo: agrega el formato de código con triples acentos graves (```) una línea antes y una después de tal código.

Comment: Hola padleiana, disculpa mi ignorancia. Podrías explicarme como es eso de agregar los triples acentos graves (```)

Comment: Lo que agregaste son triples comillas (''') que no es lo mismo. Ya te expliqué cómo se colocan; además, en la edición 7 a [esta pregunta](/posts/603994/revisions) y en la edición 3 de [esta pregunta](/posts/604213/revisions) se ve cómo se ha hecho. No olvides hacer clic en _Markdown en paralelo_ para visualizar la diferencia. Por último, no olvides que para mencionar a un usuario (y solo puedes mencionar a un usuario por comentario), debes utilizar el @.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error creo que es en la condición booleana, creo que más o menos tendría que ser así, donde valides que al menos uno de los campos está vacío

```
 if valor1.value == "" or valor2.value == "":
    valor1.error_text = "Por favor ingrese el primer valor"
    valor2.error_text = "Por favor ingrese el segundo valor"
else:
    txtresultado.value = str(int(valor1.value) + int(valor2.value))
```

Comment: Gracias @Gerson Solis